# Send push notification using Expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to send push notification using Expo, and I receive it. But there is no vibrate or sound and no pop up as well on my device. I am using Galaxy S9 with Android 9. I have not tried on Iphone yet.

Push notification is sent by nodejs and the user who installed the app will receive the push notification. User expo token is saved in firebase database. I succeed to save and fetch the token.

Below is from expo app

```
class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
  }
  async registerForPushNotificationsAsync(){
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
      Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
    );
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('chat-messages', {
        name: 'Chat messages',
        sound: true,
        priority: 'high', // was max
        vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      });
    }
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {

      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
```

Below is from nodejs server-side

```
function sendMessage(to, title, body) {
    const expo = new Expo();
    let messages = [];

    messages.push({
        to, // Expo user token
        body,
        data: { withSome: 'data' },
        ios: {
            sound: true
        },
        android: {
            "channelId": "chat-messages" //and this
        }
    })
    let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
    let tickets = [];
    (async () => {
        for (let chunk of chunks) {
            try {
                let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
                tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    })();
}
```

Also could we redirect to web page when user click the push notification?

Answer (score 2):

I see three problems on your backend code ( expo push notification docs for reference https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications/):

1. According to the docs, there should be no `ios` or `android` properties on the request body;
2. `sound` should be either `'default'` or null, instead of `true`;
3. You created the notification channel on the device, but when you send the notification, you forgot to tell which channel you are sending to.

All that said, your code that calls the expo push notifications api should look something like this:

```
messages.push({
    to, // Expo user token
    title: 'some title', //it is good practice to send title, and it will look better
    body,
    data: { withSome: 'data' },
    priority: 'high', //to make sure notification is delivered as fast as possible. see documentation for more details
    sound: true, //for iOS devices and android below 8.0
    channelId: 'chat-messages', //for devices on android 8.0 and above
})
```

I hope this helps.